# Laravel CommentsController not enough arguments passing user_id

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a Posts model that has many comments and belongs to a user, so when I want to add a comment, which belongs to a post and a user, I must give it a user a id, and this is what I tried.

```
use App\Posts;
use App\Comment;
class CommentsController extends Controller
  {
    public function store(Posts $post)
       {
          $this->validate(request(), ['body' => 'required|min:2']);
          $post->addComment(request([
               'body' => request('body'),
               'user_id' => auth()->user()]));
        }
    }
```

But what I am getting is

> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Posts::addComment(), 1
>   passed 2 expected.

The addcoment method, from the posts model:

```
public function addComment($body, User $userid)
{
    $this->comments()->create(compact('body', 'userid'));

    return back();

}
```

Following this tutorial https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/19, but the tutor skipped this step.

Comment: show your routing

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: It seems that you are passing a single argument to `addComment` function while it requires two. `request([
               'body' => request('body'),
               'user_id' => auth()->user()])`

Comment: Yes, but i wish to give it a user_id, otherwise i will get an error.

Comment: Where is route? `Route::get("/", "CommentControler@addComment")`

Comment: There is none, but this actualy used to work with only the addcomment method, until i added the relationship, comment->belongsTo(User::class).

Comment: here's how to pass it `$post->addComment(request('body'), auth()->user() );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `addComment($body, User $userid)` needs 2 arguments!

You should try something like this :

```
$post->addComment(request('body'),auth()->user());
```

<strike>OR (I'm not sure for this one)</strike> **This one below will not work.**

```
$post->addComment(request(['body' => request('body')],auth()->user());
```

Comment: It is fixed, but the second solution wich i had already tried, does not work, thanks for the answer.